# Zend_Form action and method

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Zend_Form action and method shows by default  `<form action="" method="post">`

...  My wish is not like that... Just be written `<form>` .. Is that possible ??

How can I do ???

Comment: Action is a required attribute on form, and the default value for method is GET, not POST. I really can't think of any reason why you would want to do this.

Comment: <form id="xxxx">
 <input type="text" name="yyyy" value="">
 <input type="button" onclick="pppppp();">
</form>

Comment: function ppppp() {
 jQuery.ajax({

Comment: What are you doing? What are those comments with code? Edit your question if these are important details.

Answer (score 1):

well you can simply do the following **but there really is no reason to to this!**
why would you want en empty form tag?

add this to your config to let the framework "know" your new helper

> resources.view.helperPath.My_View_Helper = "My/View/Helper"

then in the file library/My/View/Helper.php create the class

```
class My_View_Helper_Form extends Zend_View_Helper_Form
{
    /**
     * Render HTML form without any attributes on the form-tag
     *
     * @param  string $name Form name
     * @param  null|array $attribs HTML form attributes
     * @param  false|string $content Form content
     * @return string
     */
    public function form($name, $attribs = null, $content = false)
    {
        $info = $this->_getInfo($name, $content, $attribs);
        extract($info);

        if (!empty($id)) {
            $id = ' id="' . $this->view->escape($id) . '"';
        } else {
            $id = '';
        }

        if (array_key_exists('id', $attribs) && empty($attribs['id'])) {
            unset($attribs['id']);
        }

        $xhtml = '<form>';

        if (false !== $content) {
            $xhtml .= $content
                   .  '</form>';
        }

        return $xhtml;
    }
}
```

it will automatically be used when you have configured your view resource properly